# why does .htaccess rewrite behave differently based on form content?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-security

I am doing a post transaction with "having x," in the form field being submitted. My .htaccess is ensuring https: and www.  My redirect is changing the post to a get for the previously mentioned data.  If I change pretty much anything it redirects the post just fine.

What I'm looking for is for it to act like test 2, in other words forward as a post transaction with the associated post data.  It seems really odd that the content of the form could affect the behavior of the rewriting.  Any ideas are very welcome.  Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**
Per the accepted answer below, this was the host running mod-security to guard against sql injection attacks.  I could have asked them to turn it off, but decided to leave it and just check $_SERVER['REDIRECT-STATUS'] for a '403' in order to respond with an appropriate message.

---

Here is the code for my test, which I invoke with /test uri to get the form.

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($uri == '/test') {
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form 
        name="testForm" 
        method="post" 
        action="/testpost">

    <input type="text" 
           name="testName"
           value="having x,"/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="test" />

    </form> 
</body>    
</html>
<?php
} elseif ($uri == '/testpost') {
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_SERVER);
}
```

And here are the tests, showing the $_POST data and the relevant portions of $_SERVER:

> Test 1 having x,

```
array(0) {
}
array(56) {
  ["CONTENT_TYPE"]=>
  string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]=>
  string(2) "32"
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
  string(120) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"
  ["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"]=>
  string(5) "https"
  ["HTTP_X_HTTPS"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["REDIRECT_REDIRECT_HTTPS"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["REDIRECT_REDIRECT_SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(3) "443"
  ["REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  ["REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS"]=>
  string(3) "403"
  ["REDIRECT_HTTPS"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["REDIRECT_SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(3) "443"
  ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=>
  string(3) "403"
  ["HTTPS"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(3) "443"
  ["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=>
  string(5) "https"
  ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
  string(5) "39916"
  ["REDIRECT_URL"]=>
  string(10) "/403.shtml"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(9) "/testpost"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(10) "/index.php"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(10) "/index.php"
}
```

> Test 2 havng x,

In test 2 notice the misspelling of having as havng

```
array(2) {
  ["testName"]=>
  string(8) "havng x,"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
array(51) {
  ["CONTENT_TYPE"]=>
  string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]=>
  string(2) "31"
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
  string(120) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"
  ["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"]=>
  string(5) "https"
  ["HTTP_X_HTTPS"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["REDIRECT_HTTPS"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["REDIRECT_SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(3) "443"
  ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["HTTPS"]=>
  string(2) "on"
  ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(3) "443"
  ["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=>
  string(5) "https"
  ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
  string(5) "42046"
  ["REDIRECT_URL"]=>
  string(9) "/testpost"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(9) "/testpost"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(10) "/index.php"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(10) "/index.php"
}
```

It will also work with:

```
having x
having,
aving x,
having something else,
etc.
```

But will not work with

```
having something,
having somethingelse,
```

> Here is the htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your host is blocking `having x`. It thinks this is a SQL injection attack on your server. You need to talk to your host if you want them to allow this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  It seemed like a promising lead.  Unfortunately I am getting the same result.  I tried changing the uri's to /test2 and /testpost2 in case the previous 301 was causing an issue, but still no joy.  Again, I very much appreciate the thought, and regardless of whether it solved my particular problem, I'll be using the 308 in the future.  It seems more appropriate.  Thanks!

Comment: @rshermanj You're welcome! Something else must be causing it then. It could be other `RewriteRule`s or something else redirecting. Try it from another browser or another computer

Comment: Hmm, not sure what the something else could be.  I have tried firefox 71.0, chrome 79.0.3945.88, and safari 13.0.4 on one machine and chrome 78.0.3904.97 and safari 13.0.4 on another.  The host is running apache 2.4.41.  The only thing in the doc root is the .htaccess and index.php which are both included here.

Comment: @rshermanj I found out what the problem is. Your code isn't doing it.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  I just tried taking htaccess out of the equation entirely and got a 403 forbidden.  Thank you so much for your help with this!!!

Comment: btw I would up vote your answer but it seems, being new, I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @rshermanj Don't worry. I know about the limit, but thanks for clarifying.